# List<String> Modification using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, runtime

I have List like below code snippet:

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
nameList.add("Robert");
nameList.add("Tom");
nameList.add("Curran");
//robert, tom, curran
```

Now I want to modify these list values using reflection API in Java. Output something like below if we print list:

//xxx,xxx,xxx

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. Do you want to change the value after it's been aded to the list?

Comment: You need to change specific elements or the nameList object?

Comment: @AndréClérigo at runtime I want to mask/modify values of List<String>. at runtime. For example, I want to change the "Robert" to "XXX" by using reflection and similar is the case for all fields.

Comment: @Ismail I want to change all the elements inside List<String> but the condition is by using reflection only.

Comment: @AndréClérigo `List.set()`?

Comment: @AndréClérigo I know in simple cases I can use add and remove methods. But my requirement is I want to do this by using reflection at runtime.

Comment: nameList is a class attribute or a method local variable?

Comment: @Ismail it is class attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using Java reflection as follows:

The class that contains `nameList`:

```
public class SampleClass {
    List<String> nameList;
}
```

This is a simple test method using `SampleClass`:

```
@Test
public void testReflection() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    SampleClass sample= new SampleClass();
    sample.nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    sample.nameList.add("Robert");
    sample.nameList.add("Tom");
    sample.nameList.add("Curran");

    Field fieldList = SampleClass.class.getDeclaredField("nameList");
    fieldList.setAccessible(true);
    List<String> listToModify = (List<String>) fieldList.get(sample);

    for (int i =0;i<listToModify.size();i++) {
        if(listToModify.get(i).equals("Robert"))
            listToModify.set(i, "xxxxxx");
    };

    System.out.println(sample.nameList.get(0));
    System.out.println(sample.nameList.get(1));
    System.out.println(sample.nameList.get(2));
}
```

Output:

```
xxxxxx
Tom
Curran
```

**NOTE:** I don't recommend using `setAccessible(true)`, it destroys OOP encapsulation.

Comment: You can improve your solution by getting the size of the list and do List<String> value = Collections.nCopies(size_of_the_original_list, "xxxxxx");

Comment: @dreamcrash Done :), Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Tom in the question comments he said: I want to change all the elements inside List<String> but the condition is by using reflection only.

Comment: @Tom you are absolutely right. I want to modify not want to replace.

Comment: @NitishKumar I have edited my answer. I hope now this answers your question precisely.

Comment: That looks better, in my regard. I've deleted my obsolete comments

Comment: @Tom thank you for your suggestions and explanation.

Comment: You can add the custom annotation concept to solve this problem. By creating custom annotation you can simply modify those fields only whichever is required. Fields that need to be modified will be annotated with custom annotation and the rest are ignored. For reference: https://codezup.com/recursively-modify-object-values-reflection-java/.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the custom annotation concept to solve this problem. By creating custom annotation you can simply modify those fields only whichever is required. Fields that need to be modified will be annotated with custom annotation and the rest are ignored. For reference: [Java reflection](https://codezup.com/recursively-modify-object-values-reflection-java/).